# AD not replicating new group so I can give it access to a folder

Tags: powershell, automation

I hope you can help me with this issue. Simply can't seem to find any solution for it.

The Error:

```
Exception calling "AddAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity references could not be translated."
```

I start out by creating the group:

```
Try {
    Get-ADGroup -Identity $modifyGroup
} Catch {
     New-ADGroup -Name $modifyGroup -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Universal -Path $OU -ManagedBy $manager -Credential $adCred
}
```

Then I invoke onto my fileserver, and create the folder, this works fine.
After, I make a new Invoke, where I want to grant the access to the group.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname -ScriptBlock {
    $modifyGroup = $args[0];
    
    $acl = Get-ACL -Path $path
    $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($modifyGroup, "Modify", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
    $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
    Set-ACL -Path $path -AclObject$acl
} -ArgumentList $modifyGroup -Credential $serverCred
```

I have looked into the Sync-ADObject command, doesn't seem to work because then I need to know which Domain Controller I am currently connected to, and which the server I am Invoking into, is connected to. So that didn't work.
Also looked into the option using the "SID" of the new group. Doesn't work either. I get the same error..
Hopefully someone here have a suggestion :)

TIA

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know which Domain Controller I am currently connected to

This first part is easy - you can simply contact a specific domain controller when calling `New-ADGroup` with the `-Server` parameter:

```
Try {
    Get-ADGroup -Identity $modifyGroup
} Catch {
    $sourceDC = Get-ADDomainController
    $newGroup = New-ADGroup -Name $modifyGroup -Server $sourceDC -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Universal -Path $OU -ManagedBy $manager -Credential $adCred -PassThru
}
```

> and which the server I am Invoking into, is connected to

You could fetch the value of the `%LOGONSERVER%` environment variable from the remote machine to get the destination DC (it's always in UNC form, eg. `\\DC-01`, so we need to trim leading `\`'s):

```
$destinationDC = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname { $env:LOGONSERVER.TrimStart('\') }
```

At which point you can use `Sync-ADObject`:

```
Try {
    Get-ADGroup -Identity $modifyGroup
} Catch {
    $sourceDC = Get-ADDomainController
    $newGroup = New-ADGroup -Name $modifyGroup -Server $sourceDC -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Universal -Path $OU -ManagedBy $manager -Credential $adCred -PassThru
    $destinationDC = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostname { $env:LOGONSERVER.TrimStart('\') }

    Sync-ADObject -Object $newGroup -Source $sourceDC -Destination $destinationDC
}
```

Comment: Yup first part is easy indeed with the -Server. The problem lies with the $env:LOGONSERVER which is not available remotely. It doesn't return anything. :(

Comment: If I try with the $destinationDC you created here, it returns the error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"

Comment: `nltest /sc_query:DOMAINNAME` works too, to get the DC you're authenticated with.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon this command gets me DC03, where as $env:LOGONSERVER gets me DC04??